# Как раздать media файлы в django?

Tags: python, django

НЕ могу отобразить файлы из media папки при DEBUG=True, при этом файлы из static отлично работают. В чем может быть проблема!?

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "files", "media")

MEDIA_URL = "/files/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "files", "static")

STATIC_URL = "/files/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates", "static"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

Comment: Как отображаете их в шаблоне? добавьте это в вопрос. При `DEBUG=False` файлы отображаются? Для статики и медиа стоит стандартный дев сервер или nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Если в settings.py всё правильно и без ошибок, то первой причиной может быть

> `url(r'^$', ...)`

. - если есть подобные адреса, то это верный вариант(при отсутствии знака $ будут перехваты по неполному совпадению)

> Второй причиной не отображения файлов из медиa - это обращение к ним из шаблона ( причём имеет значение версия django) 
>    А наглядно можно посмотреть для версии django 1.6 тут https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iVPjZgWkHg

Answer (score 0):

что у тебя в urls.py? как выводишь медиа? что нибудь такое нужно

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL,
        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```