# Django загрузка фотографии

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, кто подскажет? Сделал поле загрузки изображения
это в **модели**

```
   scan_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d/',
                                   verbose_name='Скан документа',
                                   blank=True)
```

в **setting.py** прописал

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

При создании поста, картинка подгружается и появляется по пути указанном в модели
[image: введите сюда описание изображения], но при загрузке страницы почему то изображение помечается как формат текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще не понимаю как такое может произойти и куда смотреть

Comment: А вы не забыли настроить раздачу статических файлов из папки media в настройках вашего веб-сервера?

Comment: @andreymal не совсем понимаю, я же указал в settings.py

Comment: Настройка MEDIA_ROOT в settings.py указывает лишь то, в какой каталог будут сохраняться файлы. Но Django не занимается раздачей файлов из этого каталога, вы должны это настроить самостоятельно в настройках своего веб-сервера

Comment: @andreymal  у меня вот такая проверка идет на то что если у поста есть картика показать ее. Я не совсем какой веб сервер настроить если он и так автоматически его запускает

Comment: Встроенный веб-сервер Django не предназначен для раздачи статических файлов https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Для удобства разработки можно [добавить раздачу файлов в режиме отладки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484792), но на боевом сервере так делать нельзя

Comment: У Вас сайт сейчас где дома в разработке или у Провайдера на хостинге? Библиотека Pillow установлена?

Comment: @andreymal у меня есть такая стройка у urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @Ruin `DEBUG=True` точно включен хоть?

Comment: Включен, у меня в админке появляется ссылка на файл, но когда по ней перехожу ошибка 404 not found

Comment: Вообщем решился вопрос

просто удалил папку медиа, пересоздал посты и она появилась,и все отобразилось, только я не понял почему так было

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в шаблоне, там где нужно вывести картинку, добавить

```
{{ i.scan_image.url }}
```

Comment: Я уже решил вопрос, я так и выводил.